# How to start with the Google API for Gmail?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to receive mails from Gmail in my .NET project with Visual Studio 2022.

I've installed all required NuGet Packages, and now I'm searching for a detailed description of this API.

Which classes and methods are available?

I found something at [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app).

But I miss an **overview of the classes and methods**.

Or what does the API do?

Right now, I'm able to forward the user of my app to allow me the access to Gmail. I receive the "code", but I have to transform it into a "token2".

Do I have to send a HTTP by myself? Why can I not find a .Net function to do that for me?

Sorry for asking, but I'm searching since two hours for the answer...

Comment: I have been working with and contributing to this project for more then ten years.  There is no updated documentation https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/release_notes

Comment: I would be happy to have an old documentation. But on the page you linked, there is no description of the classes, methods, types and so on.

Comment: There is no .net specific documentation for each of the Google Apis apis.  Just general usage of the library.

Answer (score 1):

## Gmail API + Google .net client library Nuget Gmail package.

> I've installed all required NuGet Packages, and now I'm searching for a detailed description of this API.

A detailed description of the Gmail api and all its methods can be found on [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest) documentation page.  The documentation for the API lists all the methods that can be used and their required parameters and the responses.

As for the NuGet package for [Google.Apis.Gmail.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1/) there is no documentation for each of the methods related to each of the Google APIs. This library is generated from the [discovery doc](https://developers.google.com/discovery) so there will be a method in the library for each of the methods listed in the Gmail API documentation.  It is "assumed" that by consulting the Gmail API documentations you can "Determine" what method in the library you would need to use.

There is an extremally out of date documentation page for [API Client Libraries
.NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started)
 which only goes into some detail of the overall  usage of the library it self. It does not tell you how to use every method in every api that it supports.

If you can not figure it out by looking at the documentation as mentioned above then, Your best bet would be to check the assembly directly in visual studio this is something that I am able to do in Rider I would be surprised if Visual studio can not do something similar.

[image]

If you have a specific question regarding one of the methods and how to use it in the library please open a new question I would be happy to help.

## API vs Client library

> what does the API do?

The API gives you access to Gmail api.  The Gmail NuGet package gives you access to the Gmail api.

> Right now, I'm able to forward the user of my app to allow me the access to Gmail. I receive the "code", but I have to transform it into a "token2".

Depending upon which type of application the library should be handling all the authorization for you.  You shouldn't need to worry about the authorization code. Let the library do it for you.  Please consult [Authorization overview](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_overview)

> Do I have to send a HTTP by myself? Why can I not find a .Net function to do that for me?

The library will do all this for you.

```
var results = service.Users.Labels.List("me").Execute
```

Will return that response to you.

## Links

I think you should start with a few simple examples in order to understand how the Google .NET client library helps you interact with the Gmail api.

- [Gmail quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet)
- [How to Access Gmail with C# .net](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-access-gmail-with-c-net/)